# most efficient way to process a variable size dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, msmq

I'm looking for advice on the most efficient way to process a variable size dataset.i have a user requirement to provide a web interface to enable the user to upload an excel sheet containing a list of record ids, the fields to update and the new value, each row can be a different field and a different value and the number of rows can vary from a few dozen up to around 20,000. The destination table is in a Microsoft SQL database

The technology stack I'm using is C#, MVC using WCF to a custom ESB, MSMQ, Entity Framework(but i can't change table structure to enable optimistic concurrency) and MS SQL.

So parsing the datasource is fine but i'm unsure as to best way to proceed from there. 
Am i better of creating an individual message for each row or do should i parse the result set and group messages where possible(i.e where the field name and value match) into a single larger update statement and pass that as the message

And am i better to update via Entity Framework directly or use a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I always want to go for type safety. Therefore I would create a class to display your values and use a generic adapter class that handles the fetching and the updating of the values of your database.

Your display class will need something like this:

```
abstract class DisplayedValue
{
    public int Id {get; protected set;}
    public string FieldDescription {get; protected set;}
    public abstract string Value {get; set;}
}
```

We want the compiler to complain if you try to assign an integer value to a DateTime, or other invalid conversions. So we need a generic class that will hold the fetched value, and translate the displayed value into a fetched value

```
class Display<Tproperty> : Display
{
    public override string Value
    {
        get {return this.FetchValue.ToString();}
        set {this.SetValue(Parse(value));}
    }

    public Func<string, TProperty> Parse {get; set;}

    public Func<int, TProperty> FetchValue {get; set;}
    public Action <int, TProperty> SetValue {get; set;}
}
```

This class represents the original value of the property you want to display. Because I don't know the type of items you want to display in your rows (simple numbers? Guids? Customer names?), I need a Parse function that parses the string to update into a value to update.

TODO: if ToString() is not suitable to convert your property into the displayed value, consider using a Func property that converts your TProperty into a DisplayValue:

```
public Func<TProperty, string> ToDisplayValue {get; set;}
```

TODO: to increase performance, consider keeping track on whether the data has already been fetched and translated, and not fetch / translate it again if asked for.

FetchValue is a Function that takes an int Id, and returns the Tproperty value of the item that must be displayed.

UpdateValue is a void Function that takes as input an Id, and a Tproperty value to update. It updates the proper value

So to create a Display object you need:

- Id to display
- FieldDescription
- Parse function that parses the displayed value into a TProperty value
- A function to fetch the data
- A void function to update the data

Did you notice, that in this class I never mentioned that I use a database to fetch or to update the data. This is hidden in the delegate functions to Fetch and Update the data. This allows reuse to store data in other media, like variables, streams, files, etc

As an example: a SchoolDbContext with a Student:

```
class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}             // primary Key
    public DateTime Birthday {get; set;
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    ...                                   // other properties
}
class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;} // the table you want to update
    ...                                        // other tables
}
```

Suppose you want Display a row that can update the Birthday of the Student with Id myStudentId.

```
int myStudentId = ...
MyDbContext myDbContext = ...
DisplayedValue birthday = new Display<DateTime>()
{
    Id = myStudentId,
    FieldDescription = "Birthday",

    // Parse function to parse the update string to a DateTime
    Parse = (txt) => DateTime.Parse(txt),

    // function to parse the DateTime to a displayable string
    ToDisplayValue = (birthday) => birthDay.ToString("yyyy/MMM/DD"),

    // the function that fetches the Birthday of Student with Id from myDbContext:
    FetchValue = (id) => myDbContext.Students
        .Where(student => student.Id == id)
        .Select(student => student.Birthday)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    // the function that updates the Birthday of the Student with Id from myDbContext:
    UpdateValue = (id, valueToUpdate) =>
    {
         Student studentToUpdate = dbContext.Students
             .Where(student => student.Id == id)
             .SingleOrDefault();
         studentToUpdate.BirthDay = valueToUpdate);
         myDbContext.SaveChanges();            
    },
}
```

Although this is a very neat and reusable solution it is quite a lot of work for every item you want to display. If you want to automate this in a factory, you run into several problems

- You need to be sure every item needs to have an Id
- How to get the descriptive name of the displayed item? Is property name enough?

.

```
interface IId
{
    int Id {get;}
}
```

You need to be sure that every class in your DbContext that will be a DbSet derives from this interface.

```
public DisplayFactory
{
    public MyDbContext MyDbContext {get; set;}

    public Display<TProperty> Create<TEntity, TProperty>(int id,
       Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector,
       Action<TEntity, TProperty> propertyUpdater,
       Func<string, TProperty> parse,
       Func<TProperty, string> toDisplayValue)
    {
        return new Display<TProperty>()
        {
            Id = id,
            Parse = parse,
            ToDisplayValue = toDisplayValue,

            FetchValue = (id) => this.MyDbContext.DbSet<TEntity>()
                 .Where(entity => entity.Id == id) // this is where I need the interface
                 .Select(propertySelector)
                 .SingleOrDefault(),

            SetValue = (id, valueToUpdate) =>
            {
                 TEntity entityToUpdate = this.MyDbContext.DbSet<TEntity>()
                     .Where(entity => entity.Id == id)
                     .SingleOrDefault();
                 propertyUpdate(entityToUpdate, valueToUpdate);
                 SaveChanges(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
DisplayFactory factory = new DisplayFactory()
{
    MyDbContext = ...
}

DisplayedValue createdValue = factory.Create(id,
   student => student.Birthday,                   // property selector
   (student, value) => student.Birthday = value;  // property updater
   (txt) => DateTime.Parse(txt),                  // string to Datetime
   (birthday) => birthDay.ToString(...));          // to displayed birthday
```

Note, this is completely type safe, The compiler won't accept it if you want to update non-existing columns or non-existing types or want to assign incompatible types, like assigning an int to a `DateTime`. You can't by accident update another property than you just displayed.

If you still think that this is too much work, consider using reflection and `PropertyInfo` to select the `DbSet`and the Column you want to update.

Keep in mind however, that you still have to provide parsers to display and parse the displayed string values into values to update. You'll loose all type safety and the compiler will accept it if you use names of non-existing tables or columns.

I'm not sure if the extra testing time weighs up to the saved typing time.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestions, i'll try implementing them and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little helper method to update an EF entity based on a list of name/value pairs;

```
public void Update<T>(T entity, Dictionary<string, string> valuesToUpdate) where T : class
{
    var entry = ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => object.ReferenceEquals(e.Entity, entity)).Single();
    foreach (var name in valuesToUpdate.Keys)
    {
        var pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(name);
        pi.SetValue(entity, Convert.ChangeType(valuesToUpdate[pi.Name], pi.PropertyType));
        entry.Property(pi.Name).IsModified = true;
    }
}
```

And a full example of how you would use it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Color { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    }

    class Db : DbContext
    {

        public void Update<T>(T entity, Dictionary<string, string> valuesToUpdate) where T : class
        {
            var entry = ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => object.ReferenceEquals(e.Entity, entity)).Single();
            foreach (var name in valuesToUpdate.Keys)
            {
                var pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(name);
                pi.SetValue(entity, Convert.ChangeType(valuesToUpdate[pi.Name], pi.PropertyType));
                entry.Property(pi.Name).IsModified = true;
            }
        }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }



        class Program
        {


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                    db.Database.Initialize(true);
                }
                int id;
                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);

                    var c = db.Cars.Create();
                    c.Color = 2;
                    c.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;

                    db.Cars.Add(c);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    id = c.Id;

                }

                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);

                    var c = new Car() { Id = id };
                    var updates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    updates.Add(nameof(Car.Color), "3");
                    updates.Add(nameof(Car.UpdateDate), "2017-01-02");
                    db.Cars.Attach(c);

                    db.Update(c, updates);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the UPDATE EF Generates:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Cars]
SET [Color] = @0, [UpdateDate] = @1
WHERE ([Id] = @2)

-- @0: '3' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: '1/2/2017 12:00:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2)

-- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)
```

Note that only the changed attributes are modified, Name is not.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestions, i'll try implementing them and let you know how it goes